# Moving triangles to a new column with triangle strip

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm having problems moving triangles to another column. I'm able to successfully add them to right direction (in the picture), but when I want to move them into a new column it takes points from old points (furthest on the right) and I would like to have them connected to the upper triangles as I elevate the mesh, the strip will make the mesh rise.

```
// triangles without a new column
std::vector<triangle_vertices_t> vertices = {
    { {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1} },
    { {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1} },
    { {0, 0, 0 + 1}, {1, 0, 0 + 1}, {0, 0, 1 + 1} },
    { {1, 0, 0 + 1}, {0, 0, 1 + 1}, {1, 0, 1 + 1} }
};
```

[image: triangles single column]

```
// vertices with a new column
std::vector<triangle_vertices_t> vertices = {
    { {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1} },
    { {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1} },
    { {0, 0, 0 + 1}, {1, 0, 0 + 1}, {0, 0, 1 + 1} },
    { {1, 0, 0 + 1}, {0, 0, 1 + 1}, {1, 0, 1 + 1} },
    { {1 - 1, 0, 0}, {1 - 1, 0, 1}, {0 - 1, 0, 1} },
    { {-1, 0, 0}, {1 - 1, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 1} },
};
```

[image: triangles with column]

```
//drawing the triangles
glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 3 * amount_of_triangles);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

So my question is, how can I add a column while connecting to the upper triangles?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On possibility is to use [Primitive Restart](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart) inidces.

Another simple trick is to add the last vertex and the first vertex of a strip twice:

```nona
A       C     E      G
  +---- +-----+-----+
  |   / |   / |   / |
  | /   | /   | /   |
B +-----+-----+-----+
  |   / | D   F      H
  | /   |
  +-----+
I        J
```

Triangle strip:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H - H - B - B - I - D - J
```

This works because with a triangular primitive with 2 identical points nothing at all is rasterized. Hence the "triangles" `G - H - H`, `H - H - B`, `H - B - B` and `B - B - I` do not generate any fragments.

Comment: One question still remains, how do I connect the upper row with the bottom rom ( added new picture)?

Comment: @pesuww Same approach. If you want to restart a triangle strip, then you have to add the last vertex and the first vertex of the parts twice. But actually I don't exactly know what you mean. Anyway that seems to be a completely new question. So please [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).